# how to assign a value to a text view in another layout on android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have two layouts a bus and a taxi layout and another header layout.the header layout is displayed on both the taxi and the bus layout.the header layout has a text view and i wanted to set the value of the header text view from the class of the two layouts.i wanted to show the number of buses or taxis on the header 
this is the code for the bus layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the code for the taxi layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

now based on which layout is displayed i wanted to set the value of the text view on the header layout form the class using java code.
this is the header layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeaderText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="     "
        android:background="#fffff0"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

please help

Comment: Are you just need to know how to set value for `TextView`?

Comment: You already added the header to every layout. so, just set the HeadetText textview value from the activity

Comment: i tried to do this but its not working                               LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)BUs.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.element));
  TV = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  TV.setText(value);

Comment: wait i will give you an example

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to set the Layout with ContentView:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Second, you have to get the reference of the TextView:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HeaderText);
```

Then, you just need to set the text:

```
textView.setText("your string!");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i got same problem, but this is not solving the problem of `another layout`

Answer (score 3):

Using Layout Inflater, based on your problem :

```
setContentView(R.layout.bus_layout); // Or R.layout.taxi_layout

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);

TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.HeaderText);

tv.setText("value of header text");
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem of the `TextView` being in another `Layout`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should call `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_name);` in activity to load content. After that call

```
TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HeaderText);
TV.setText(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like a normal views added to your xml. In your both activity you need to set TextView value like this :

```
TextView tvHeaderText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HeaderText);
tvHeaderText.setText("set what you want to show");
```

I tested this. Give it a try.

Comment: i tried this it doesn't work the header is just a layout it doesn't have a class associated with it if that has something to do with it i wanted to change the value from another class